How can I make grease pencil operate more like pixel art software?
TL;DR: Can brushes in Grease Pencil be easily converted into geometric shapes and locked to a grid, like how pixel art software operates?
Hi everyone,
I’ve been exploring creating pixel art-style artwork, where pixels are locked to a grid, but with the added flexibility of incorporating geometric shapes (see examples). I understand that the grid functionality was temporarily removed in Grease Pencil 3.0 but is expected to return. My question is: is it currently possible—or will it be in the future—to paint while locked to a grid, similar to how dedicated pixel art software works?
I’m completely new to Grease Pencil and would really appreciate any advice or pointers in the right direction. Any information is welcome!
Why Blender?

I want to take advantage of Blender’s material system.
My experience with vector software has been mixed (the examples were created directly with SVG code).

I’m a software engineer, so creating an add-on for this functionality isn’t off the table. However, having some starter info or tips before diving in would be incredibly helpful :)
Thanks in advance for your help!



It is perfectly possible to make pixel-art in Blender and there are definitely add-ons and extensions that exist to help users make it (I haven't looked into it yet) as well. In fact, it is so common that there is a pixel-art tag on this very website that distinguishes questions relating to making pixel-art with blender. The real question is why do you need to make pixel-art with grease pencil?

It is not that grease pencil can't be used to make pixel art; it is just that it is not designed for it. So, it baffles me why you need this extra condition to make pixel art when you can do so easily without a grease pencil object.
